# How to write a test case for Angular Material modal

Tags: angular, angular-material, jasmine, angular-test

component.ts file

```
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
constructor(private _matDialog: MatDialog) { }
 onOpenModal(template) {
    this._matDialog.open(template);
  }
```

How to write a test case for the above method, using Angular's `ng test`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test, just if the `this._matDialog.open()` function is called, or do you want to check if the dialog is opened in DOM and get information out of the dialog instance? Also what have you tried already?